# Shiny app UIoutput - issue with creating elements dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame (df) with column names var1 and var2 are factors. I’m trying to create a dynamic list of variable 2 based on the input chosen by user for variable 1.

When I run the following statement at the command line in R:  sort(unique(df$var2[df$var1 %in% c("a", "b")])), I get the result as expected, an output is list of factor variables that meets the criteria, in this case x, y.

However, when I use the following code in my shiny app, it returns the indexes of x and y. Would anyone know what may be the issue as to why the indexes are returned and how I might be able to resolve it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

UI:

```
uiOutput("var2Output")
```

Server:

```
output$var2Output <- renderUI({
   selectInput("var2Input", "Var2",
               (sort(unique(df$var2[df$var1 %in% c("a", "b")]))),
               selected = "x")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch is, the `choices` parameter for `selectInput` has the following documentation

> List of values to select from. If elements of the list are named then
>   that name rather than the value is displayed to the user.

So you need to remove the names.

Comment: changing the code to include as.character resolved the issue output$var2Output <- renderUI({
   selectInput("var2Input", "Var2",
               (sort(unique(as.character(df$var2[df$var1 %in% c("a", "b")])))),
               selected = "x")
})